# Log4View - Log level not showing correct log level messages

Tags: log4net, log4view

Unable to see the log messages according to the level selected. See the image below

[I have selected INFO level but still it is showing all 3 types of message level.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ktx.png)

[This is my config file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Ze8.png). Appender 'AllAppender' is used.
If I choose Fields Level so it is showing me Fields and Grid level Log.[Here you can see the level settings in Log4View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bqw.png)

Comment: You need to show how you've configured the logging framework/library. An image of your IDE that further describes what you've already stated isn't helpful.

Comment: LOG4View Settings or Log4Net Settings